# Mounted iso image at document root but can't browse it

Tags: mount, iso

I have an ISO image of CentOS 7:

```
[root ~]# file /home/myhome/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso 
/home/myhome/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'CentOS 7 x86_64                ' (bootable)
```

I want it to be seen on my web server's document root so I mount it like this:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/myhome/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso /var/www/html
```

Mount shows it mounted and httpd.conf confirms that /var/www/html is the document root. And, I can see CentOS-7 files and directories in /var/www/html.

```
/home/myhome/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso on /var/www/html type iso9660 (ro,loop=/dev/loop0)
```

But, when I browse to the server's home page I just get the Apache test page. I did restart httpd. What am I missing?

Comment: What's in your apache error log?  Maybe post your relevant DocumentRoot section from `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Does the Apache test page specify the steps needed to not see the test page in the future?  [This has happened before](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/03/24/tuttle_centos/).

Comment: Ok, the error log shows that I'm trying to access document root, which has no index file, and the directive is set to forbid listing the directory contents. And, sure enough, when I reference a subdirectory from my browser, I can see it. So, I need to figure out where virt-manager needs to look for the OS install. But, that's a separate question.

Comment: So, the resolution was to comment out everything in welcome.conf. It's odd that the error pointed to an Index directive problem even though httpd.conf explicitly allowed indexing of the /var/www/html path. @TimothyMartin If you create an answer with your resolution I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the `Apache test page` you'll need to comment out all entries in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` and then restart or reload `apache`.

Answer (score 0):

An ISO image file is an archive, and as such needs to be extracted into a folder in which the contents can be browsed.  For example, try right-clicking the program 7-zip and select the Extract To folder option.

Comment: Actually, the mount with the magic options gives you a directory you can navigate. No extraction needed!